# ckeditor class on paragraph is not being recognized

Tags: javascript, css, class, ckeditor, paragraph

Good day to all. I need to put a class on paragraph tags in ckeditor. Inside config.js I added:

...

```
config.format_p = { element : 'p', attributes : { class : 'whatever' } };
```

...

as in http://docs.cksource.com/ckeditor_api/symbols/CKEDITOR.config.html#.format_p.

The problem is that the class is not being recognized (paragraphs still don't have any class). Can anyone help pls?

Answer (score 0):

You might need to be more specific with your styling. If the paragraphs are inside a div named foo such as..

```
<div id="foo">
    <p class="bar">paragraph text</p>
    <p class="bar">paragraph text</p>
</div>
```

Then declare your style in the css file as (sample style declarations given)

```
#foo p.bar {
   color: #f3f3f3;
   font-weight: bold;
}
```

It helps to target the paragraphs where they are respective to the DOM to get the desired results. I hope this helps.